# Cameras rotation is too slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a game object that moves and rotates. I want the camera to stay behind the object all the time, so when the user presses w, it will look like the gameobject moves forward. 
This is my skript for the camera movement.

```
public Transform target;
public Vector3 offset;

public void FixedUpdate()
{
transform.position = target.TransformPoint(offset);
transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

But I camera is not rotating around the player fast enough, so it looks like he is moving sidewards.

This is my player movement script, but I don't see any mistake in there.

```
public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public float forwardSpeed;
public float sideSpeed;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        Vector3 movement = transform.rotation * Vector3.forward / (100 / forwardSpeed);
        transform.Translate(movement);

    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        Vector3 movement = transform.rotation * Vector3.back / (100 / sideSpeed);
        transform.Translate(movement);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        Vector3 movement = transform.rotation * Vector3.left / (100 / sideSpeed);
        transform.Translate(movement);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        Vector3 movement = transform.rotation * Vector3.right / (100 / sideSpeed);
        transform.Translate(movement);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("e"))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("q"))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, -1, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqNYu.gif)

When the object moves sidewards it should move forwards.
Here are my settings in Unity:
[image]

Comment: maybe you can just parent the camera to that gameObject?

Comment: also doesn't work. I added the movement of the player

Comment: if you just parent the camera, you can disable your camera script

Comment: I did that, but still doesn't work

Comment: It would help if you included screenshots or a gif of what it looks like. Use something like [this](https://www.screentogif.com/) to share what's happening with this code.

Comment: Also as an aside, instead of using `transform.rotation * Vector3.right` /`Vector3.left`/`Vector3.forward`/`Vector3.back` you can use `transform.right`/`-1f * transform.right`/`transform.forward`/`-1f * transform.forward` It's more conventional/readable and maybe faster.

Comment: I added a gif .

Comment: Why would it rotate? You're doing LookAt() on the target; its rotation doesn't matter. It will only look at the position.

Comment: The easiest way is definitely to child the camera to an arm attached to the player, let me know if you need a conceptual explaination

Comment: The rotation isn't its issue; it's the position. When you rotate the player you still want the camera to look at the player but you want its position to be shifted to stay behind the player (the cylinder that's rotating). So if you put it as a child on the player and move it to behind the player you should - like @zambari writes - be fine. If this doesn't work please show us what you've done and why it doesn't work.

Comment: I added my settings in Unity to the question. It still doesn't work

Comment: @FredrikSchön Do you see any mistake?

Comment: Sorry Patrick, I do not. The screenshot of Unity looks good. Perhaps if you add a screenshot of the Player object as well, just to make sure that it's the cylinder object that we're seeing. But just to be clear; when you child the camera, what happens when you move/rotate the Player? You should get the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it in a new project